# Enable html radio buttom when checkbox selected (basic JS or CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a 2 radio buttons and a checkbox as shown in below code and fiddle..

```
<body>
<input type = "radio"/> Love
<input type = "radio"/> Hate
<input type = "Checkbox"/> Just do it!
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jjaleel/3n1ngwy0/

When the checkbox is checked, I want the radio button 'Love' to be automatically selected.

The simplest Javascript or CSS code code is what I need.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you actually tried? Would be good to post whatever JS you have attempted, so we can help.

Comment: Not possible with CSS given the current HTML structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `onclick()` event handler to auto select the radio button.

```html
<body>
    <input type = "radio" name="loh" id="love1"/> Love
    <input type = "radio" name="loh"/> Hate
    <input type = "Checkbox" onclick="document.getElementById('love1').checked = (this.checked === true) ? true : document.getElementById('love1').checked;"/> Just do it!
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this(this would go at the bottom of the body):

```
document.getElementById("YOURCHECKBOXID").onchange = function() {
    document.getElementsById("input")[0].checked = true;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9mm2swmz/